# Uploading zipped up virus

Tags: appsec, virus, file-upload

Lets say that I have a badly-made file upload on a website. Someone uploads a zip file which contains a virus. Why would they do this? Surely the zip file is useless unless it is opened and the contents are executed?

Comment: Are you sure this was an actual human doing this? It's most likely a bot who just floods all file upload forms with zipper up malware, hoping that the form's files end up being processed by a stupid user who would unzip it and execute it.

Comment: It could be anything, the question is hypothetical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Why this happened? You can only speculate. Might not be a purposeful action at all. Maybe a malicious person hopes someone does exactly what you describe. The zip might have a name that motivates someone to do so like "your-bosses-private-emails.zip" or sth like this.

Comment: ah I see, so it is left in the hope someone might download it. Thanks for your answer